# Hive UDF only works in standalone select statement and not in "Create table as select..." or "insert into .. select.."

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-udf

I have a Generic UDF which encrypts a given input value. This UDF gives the correct value when used in a select statement however the UDF returns null when used in "Create table as select" or "Insert into .. select" statement. Input to the udf, output from udf, data type of the table column being created or inserted into, all are of type string.

So what could be the reason behind the select statement behaving differently when part of create or insert statement?

Comment: One wild guess: What happens when you created the table before insert? Also try to cast(your_udf() as string) as colname in the query to make the type explicitly defined

Comment: same.. inserting after creating the table and casting did not help